# dlib mlp::kernel_1a_c member initialization inside a class

Tags: c++, class, neural-network, private, dlib

I'm using dlib with the neural network example.
[dlib neural network](http://dlib.net/mlp_ex.cpp.html)

I get the error:

**error: no matching function for call to ‘dlib::mlp_kernel_c::mlp_kernel_c()**

I am trying to initialize the

"mlp::kernel_1a_c net(2,5);"

variable inside a class, but I get all kinds of errors. Here is the piece of code **relevant to my issue**:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include <dlib/mlp.h>
typedef dlib::mlp::kernel_1a_c mlp_trainer_type;
Class MyClass:
 public:
  MyClassConstructure()
  {
     /// After declaration, how do I initialize my_neural_network_ here?
     // my_neural_network_(5, 5);  ????
  }
 private:
  /* this part fails, even without using the typedef. */
  mlp_trainer_type mouth_neural_network_;
 #end
```

Won't work even if I do:

```
private:
  mlp_trainer_type mouth_neural_network_(2,5);
```

Or if I declare and define it as a public variable.
How do I solve this problem? I don't want a global variable.

I also use the SVM library from dlib, and that one works inside my class. It's just MLP that does not work.

The program worked just using dlib's SVM until I included that neural private variable today.

Comment: Seems to be more of a C++ syntax than a linking issue. I just can't figure out the appropriate way to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are trying to use `mlp_kernel_c` does not have a default constructor.  You need to initialize the member variable before you enter the constructor body:

```cpp
MyConstructor() : mouth_neural_network_(2,5)
{
     //Other stuff
}
```

Comment: S***. That was a tricky one. I'm so used to making classes with at least one constructure, so I had never seen this error before.

Comment: but, wait...it does have a default constructure. The reason why it works is because you can only initialize a non-static data member in the initialization list, which is the syntax that you suggested above